# ESP8266 not waking up?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

i have been playing around with my ESP8266 devkit board and i have found some strange results, the module when put to sleep NEVER wakes up unless restarted. although specified in the documentation [here](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/node/#nodesleep) that it can be done. I have modified the line needed but i found something strange that it only said to comment out 1 line regarding `PMSLEEP_ENABLE` when doing that the module refused until i commented out another line `TIMER_SUSPEND_ENABLE` which i noticed the comment beside at first but thought to follow the instructions of the makers.

now however trying to put the module to sleep is not working , everytime the module goes to sleep with `int_type` property set to `node.INT_BOTH`, the module wouldnt wake up unless i restart it via switch on the board. so for a workaound i would put the module to sleep with the `int_type` property set to `node.LOW` or `node.High` however neither of them work, the module does go to sleep briefly i can see the current dropping then the module just restarts with a watchdog timer reset.

any ideas for reliable ways to put the module to sleep ? or am i just doing something wrong that i completely missed?

sorry for my bad English but i hope i explained it well enough.

**EDIT**

Further debugging i found out that i cannot use the same pin in my programming and at the same time use that same pin to wake the module up , meaning if i have a sensor connected to pinX and use the change value function to wake up the module and this same pinX i am using somewhere else in my code with interrupts whatsoever then it wont work , what i did as a workaround for that is use a different pin and use the same output from my switch to wake the module up, this however can only be done through levels as when the module sleeps it does not detect at all the rising and falling edges.

Comment: I've answered on the issue that you raised.  Perhaps you need to look at your electrical design.  Is your pin floating?

Comment: @TerryE my pin configuration is floating yes however i am using a 3 pin switch with the output connected to the mcu and the normally opened and closed connected to vcc and gnd, i have also tried making the gpio configuration to pullup and making the switch when closed connected to ground, however that still wont give reliable results 
by reliable results i mean it works once doesnt work the other for example to wake the module up with node.INT_LOW i have to press the switch one time , that brings it to low and does nothing then press it again and it works , its always 2 times needed not once

Comment: and also thats not debouncing since measuring the voltage on the pin it is 0.00 volts on my multimeter when the switch is pressed the gpio pull up configuration for the gpio pin enabled so i am sure its going to low , i have also tested the gpio routines to verify i am using the correct pin and it is the correct pin

i have also tried testing on another nodemcu board and it gave the same results

Comment: Mechanical relays (or any contact) bounce and very fast.  Don't trust a multimeter.  If you want to catch the dynamic then you need to invest in something like a BitScope.  You can see this even if you just use `gpio.trig()` to log the `tmr.now()` values for `up` triggers in an array.  (Don't print then on the fly as the printing is a lot slower than the bounces)  You need to "dead band" the relay for maybe 100 mSec after first break/contact. If you search "debounce relay nodemcu", then you'll get lots of hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out even re initializing the port doesnt change the intialization, thus as a workaround , a new port must be used just to wake and sleep the module which is strange since if i re initialized the port using the appropriate lines it still wont change the mode as far as i understand through debugging